# iOS Xcode: Compiler error accessing Ivar in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, clang

I am working in a large existing objective-c codebase, writing unit tests at the moment. The project uses instance variables widely.

I wrote a little method to grab the ivar for something. It worked in another unit test in the same project, but isn't working in this case.

Code:

```
-(id)getObjectForIvarNamed:(NSString *)ivarNameString
 {
    const char *ivarName = [ivarNameString UTF8String];

    Ivar ivarValue = class_getInstanceVariable([textFieldOverlay class], ivarName);
    id objectAtIvar = object_getIvar(textFieldOverlay, ivarValue);

    return objectAtIvar;
}
```

The compiler complains at the line starting `Ivar ivarValue` with the following error:

`"Declaration of 'Ivar' must be imported from module 'ObjectiveC.runtime' before it is required"`

A web search for this error code comes up with zero hits. Not sure why it works in another file, the headers all look the same between the two `XCUnitTest` classes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Never fails, found the answer as soon as I had typed the question. *But*, I hadn't posted yet. Because this error was impossible to find in a web search, I figured I should post it, so there is an instance out there. The project's class I was testing in the working test class imports the objective-c runtime header, I thought to check the tested class after I typed the question up. I thought it was a header issue but didn't see it in the imported class. Learning moment.

To import the objective-c runtime header and eradicate this warning, add `#import <objc/runtime.h>` to the header. Done, and done.